# Отловить появление AlertDialog в другом приложении

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Есть чужое приложение, которое в некоторый момент выводит AlertDialog.
Вопрос: как можно отловить появление этого диалога в своём приложении?
Допускается использование всех прелестей root+busybox.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Я бы покопался в исходниках `WindowManagerService`.

В грубом приближении:

1. Пишем сервис, который мониторит стек активити через `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks()` и при появлении нужного приложения делает "стойку".
2. Далее каким-то образом надо получить инстанс `WindowServiceManager` (без понятия, как) и ждем появления в стеке окошек `AlertDialog`. До списка окошек можно достучаться через рефлексию, например, вызовом `WindowServiceManager.dumpWindows()`.

Такие вот наводки - по крайней мере я бы копал в этом направлении.

**Update**
Это вы называете хардкором? Да это так, детские шалости. Менее хардкорно можно попробовать половить логи, правда, начиная с JB (4.1) логи видны без пермишена только руту - так что может оказаться это более хардкорным.

Comment: Ух, как хардкорно. Вполне вероятно, что проблема решается намного проще, если подойти к ней с другой стороны. Ибо недаром же Android не приветствует вмешательство одного в жизненный цикл другого.

Comment: @0xFFh см. апдейт ответа.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, поковырялся в исходниках WindowServiceManager, ничего полезного не нашёл (наверное, плохо искал).

Comment: @SuperCreeper надо искать как получить инстанс `WindowServiceManager` - в самом исходнике ничего на эту тему нет - согласен. Надо копаться дальше или посмотреть перехват через логи (см. выше)

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, пока что я придумал вот такое очень велосипедное и тормозное "решение": раз в несколько секунд с помощью root+busybox делаю скриншот, далее декодирую его в Bitmap, а потом считываю некоторые пиксели - если там окажутся цвета бэкграунда AlertDialog (размер и текст всегда одинаковы), то выполняю некоторое действие.  

Сейчас я хочу покопаться в исходниках, начиная с AlertDialog и далее по цепочке. Самое веселье в том, что чужое приложение показывает диалог из C++ кода, но это наверно не имеет значения.